# Trigger JOB for Java EE Application

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are currently migrating a simple Java EE Application in the cloud and have the following Use Case:

In the Application there are some Jobs scheduled to start evry 22 PM. The Jobs clean some Data in the Database, and also produce some Report File (in the S3) for the customer.

In the cloud a concurrency problem between the jobs can occurs. Then we don’t have only 1 Application Server anymore but more than one EC2 instances on there the application are running parallel.

What is the best way to realize that in the AWS Cloud. We want to trigger the job with something outside the Application (Lamdda Funktion?). It is a Rest Application …

Comment: start a good old cron job on one of your server or if you use J2EE a good API is quartz to schedule jobs and can be configured in cluster mode http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering

Comment: the other option as you mentioned is to use [an AWS Lambda Function on a Schedule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/RunLambdaSchedule.html)

Comment: It's not really clear what the lambda function should invoke. A rest service ?  Can’t find  any example!

Comment: your lambda can [directly access the RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html) to clean your data